# How to iterate through the indices of a Boost Multi_index container?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index, boost-preprocessor

I have a `boost::multi_index::multi_index_container` container having six different `ordered_non_unique` indices. The idea is to be able to sort the data along these six indices (as a means of ranking solutions using multiple criteria).

The issue I'm facing is while retrieving the indices in a loop. Boost requires me to use the following syntax to get (say) the 4th index:

`const result_multi::nth_index<1>::type &legs_index = result.get<4>();`

What I'm trying to do is to put the above statement in a loop that runs between 0 to 5, so that I can use the same code on all six indices. Of course, the following code fragment would not compile:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  const result_multi::nth_index<1>::type &index = result.get<i>();
  ...
  ... Display result sorted along the i-th index
  ...
 }
```

As the `get<i>` is a template that needs to be defined during compilation.

How can I use achieve the above functionality so that I don't need to duplicate the code 6 times? It seems `boost:preprocessor` may help in doing so, but am unable to figure out exactly how to use it - any pointers would be really appreciated!

**EDIT**: I would really appreciate a non-C++11 solution as well, to complement the excellent answer using one. (For non-technical reasons, I'm forced to use a legacy version of gcc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use C++14, the backporting to C++03 with Boost could look like this:

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2b6a9c908870ca3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/type_traits/integral_constant.hpp>

template<typename T,T N0,T N1,typename F>
void static_for(F f)
{
  static_for<T,N0,N1>(f,boost::integral_constant<bool,(N0<N1)>());
}

template<typename T,T N0,T N1,typename F>
void static_for(F f,boost::true_type)
{
  f(boost::integral_constant<T,N0>());
  static_for<T,N0+1,N1>(f);
}

template<typename T,T N0,T N1,typename F>
void static_for(F f,boost::false_type)
{
}

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;
typedef multi_index_container<
  int,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int> >,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int>,std::greater<int> >,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int> >,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int>,std::greater<int> >,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int> >,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int>,std::greater<int> >
  >
> result_multi;

#include <iostream>

struct body
{
  body(result_multi& result):result(result){}

  template<typename I>
  void operator()(I){
    typename result_multi::nth_index<I::value>::type& index=
      result.get<I::value>();

    std::cout<<"index #"<<I::value<<": ";
    for(typename result_multi::nth_index<I::value>::type::iterator
          b=index.begin(),
          e=index.end();
        b!=e;++b){
      std::cout<<*b<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
  }

  result_multi& result;
};

int main()
{
  result_multi result;
  for(int i=0;i<3;++i)result.insert(i);

  static_for<int,0,6>(body(result));
}
```

which is considerably uglier. Another alternative is to use the preprocessor with [`BOOST_PP_REPEAT`](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/repeat.html). I'm not sure myself which solution looks best, though I think I'd favor the first as it's better prepared for C++14 upgrading:

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b4f74fc4e3df6dd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;
typedef multi_index_container<
  int,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int> >,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int>,std::greater<int> >,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int> >,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int>,std::greater<int> >,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int> >,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int>,std::greater<int> >
  >
> result_multi;

#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  result_multi result;
  for(int i=0;i<3;++i)result.insert(i);

#define BODY(z,i,_)                                        \
{                                                          \
  result_multi::nth_index<i>::type& index=result.get<i>(); \
                                                           \
  std::cout<<"index #"<<i<<": ";                           \
  for(result_multi::nth_index<i>::type::iterator           \
        b=index.begin(),                                   \
        e=index.end();                                     \
      b!=e;++b){                                           \
    std::cout<<*b<<" ";                                    \
  }                                                        \
  std::cout<<"\n";                                         \
}

BOOST_PP_REPEAT(6,BODY,~)

#undef BODY
}
```

Comment: Ended up going for the latter option, as it has minimal boilerplate code!

Answer (score 1):

You need some metaprogramming to do this, namely replacing the run-time `for` with a compile-time construct that can iterate over *types* representing the constants 0,...,5. A very simple `static_for` relying on C++14 capabilities is shown below. Note that the generic lambda function substituting for the `for` body is passed a [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)  `i` whose *numerical value* is obtained through `operator()`, hence the "`i()`" in "`auto& index=result.get<i()>();`".

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98336b1ea172d507)</kbd>**

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T,T N0,T N1,typename F>
void static_for(F f)
{
  static_for<T,N0,N1>(f,std::integral_constant<bool,(N0<N1)>{});
}

template<typename T,T N0,T N1,typename F>
void static_for(F f,std::true_type)
{
  f(std::integral_constant<T,N0>{});
  static_for<T,N0+1,N1>(f);
}

template<typename T,T N0,T N1,typename F>
void static_for(F f,std::false_type)
{
}

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using result_multi=multi_index_container<
  int,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int>>,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int>,std::greater<int>>,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int>>,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int>,std::greater<int>>,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int>>,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<int>,std::greater<int>>
  >
>;

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  result_multi result={0,1,2};

  static_for<int,0,6>([&](auto i){
    auto& index=result.get<i()>();

    std::cout<<"index #"<<i()<<": ";
    for(int x:index)std::cout<<x<<" ";
    std::cout<<"\n";
  });
}
```

**Output:**

```
index #0: 0 1 2 
index #1: 2 1 0 
index #2: 0 1 2 
index #3: 2 1 0 
index #4: 0 1 2 
index #5: 2 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the c++11 answer! Unfortunately, I don't have access to a c++11 compiler at my workplace (but that fortunately allows me to use boost!), so if you can post another answer using boost and/or preprocessor macros, I'd be most happy to accept it! (Your answer is currently useful to me in a different context - help convince people to upgrade gcc!)